# Angular dropdown ng-change event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-change

I have a angular dropdown **cmbAll** and list of **cmbFruit** in ng-repeat. I want when i change cmbAll selected value on cmbFruit [i] also change. But on load cmbAll is populated with -1 indexselected and cmbFruit [i] with their specific indexex. Below is the code. Please suggest.

```
<select id="cmbAll"  tabindex="" title="" ng-change="onChange()">
                                <option value="">-Select One-</option>
                                <option value="1">Apple</option>
                                <option value="2">Banana</option>
                                <option value="3">Mango</option>
                                <option value="4">Papaya</option>
                                <option value="5">Pear</option>
  </select>
   <div data-ng-repeat="x in InfoList">
     <select id="cmbFruit" name="cmbFruit" ng-model="x.Name"
       ng-options="c.Value as c.Text    for c in x.List"></select>

   </div>
```

What should be the code for **onchange()**

Comment: Having a difficult time understanding what is being asked here...

Comment: yes, please provide some more explanation with example, and provide the code if you tried something yet.

Comment: Do you want to change the selected element in the second dropdown (cmbFruit) based on selection made in the first dropdown(cmbAll) ?

Comment: I want it to change for all the values of ng-repeat  element in the second dropdown (cmbFruit) based on selection made in the first dropdown(cmbAll)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take ng-model for `cmbAll`

```
<select id="cmbAll"  tabindex="" title="" ng-change="onChange()" ng-model="cmbAll">
        <option value="">-Select One-</option>
        <option value="1">Apple</option>
        <option value="2">Banana</option>
        <option value="3">Mango</option>
        <option value="4">Papaya</option>
        <option value="5">Pear</option>
</select>
<div data-ng-repeat="x in InfoList">
    <select id="cmbFruit" name="cmbFruit" ng-model="x.Name"
    ng-options="c.Value as c.Text for c in x.List"></select>

</div>
```

Controller.

```
  $scope.onChange = function()
{
   for(var i=0 ; i <  $scope.InfoList.length; i++)
            {
                $scope.InfoList[i].name  = $scope.cmbAll
            }

}
```

This will assign the value selected in `cmbAll` to second dropdown.

Comment: I want it to change for all the values of ng-repeat dropdown

Comment: didn't get you completely, what should happen when you select apple?

Comment: according to my understanding, if first option is selected from first drop down, the second drop down's first option should be selected right?

Comment: I changed my answer now, please check.

Comment: Thanx for the answer sravan...at the controller end i am getting the changed values but at Angular UI(html), i get dropdown with no fruit selected.